# Transfering data from Rails 3 app to C# desktop app

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails

It's one of those questions that I think I know how to solve, but if I don't look it up - I can end up reinventing the wheel.

Here's the task.

I have a C# app, that needs to contact my Rails 3 app every minute, and get information from there.

I would do it like so:

- Make a POST request from C# app to Rails website (containing secret key or username / password of some sort)
- website makes sure password is correct
- makes some requests to the database
- gets an object (model), and
- responds with a string, maybe something like this:

  ```
  @response = ""

  if secretkey == '123'

  @item = Item.find(1)
  @response = @item.name + "|" + @item.price + ...

  end
  ```

  and then just return @response in a view or `render :text` back to C# app.

Is this a smart way to do it?
Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is creating a service (with API) in Rails and accessing it via a networked client.

The proper approach would be to implement:

- Authentication: preferably OAUTH2
- API: define your Resources. Look into RESTful APIs, you also may decide to use RABL gem to describe your APIs
- Implement controllers that serialize your data to something consumable. I'd suggest JSON or XML, not TEXT.